# Cucumber tests with tags are slow

Tags: performance, tags, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

I've noticed that if I have multiple feature files (around 40) with tag @api and try to run them with maven surefire plugin, its slow like hell. With parallel execution I expected something like 10 seconds.

Every single feature file takes about 1.5 seconds to run, but whole build takes more than two minutes! Is it because of slow tag search? Can I somehow improve the performance?

Tests directory tree:

```
test
  |-api
    |-fe
    |  feature1
    |  feature2
    |-mw
      feature3
      feature4
```

Maven command:

```
test
-Dtags="@api"
-Denvironment=${ENVIRONMENT}
-Ddirectory=src/test/resources/features/api/
-DparallelScheme=SCENARIO
```

Test log:

```
1 Scenarios (1 passed)
1 Steps (1 passed)
0m1.545s
.
.
1 Scenarios (1 passed)
1 Steps (1 passed)
0m1.586s

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-08T10:21:43+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/672M
```